# Assocation between class and state

Tags: uml

Is it possible to show on a UML diagram a relationship between class and state? There is a base class with an associated state machine. I need to derive from the base class some specific classes and associate them somehow with the states of the base class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends: If you refer to the UML as an abstract concept, then of course. Even if you do not know a notation (due to lack of information or the notation does not exist) you can coin your own. If you want to achieve this with a certain software, then of course you have to choose the notation from the possibilities offered by the software. This should not be a big problem, however, if you coin your own notation, then of course you have to describe somewhere the meaning of the new notation.